# Sorting a DropDownList when using AS in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am having trouble sorting a drop down list.

I have tried a few different ways I have found on here using dataviews but cannot get them to work.

Here is my code that creates the drop down list I want to be sorted by [Last Name].

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] + ' ' + [Email] + ' ' + [Phone] AS [FullInfo] FROM [Official]"

con.Close()
con.Open()

Dim dt = New DataTable
Using sqlconnecton = New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
    Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, con)
        da.Fill(dt)
    End Using
End Using

DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

UPDATE 1

I should not have tried to simplify this question. How my query is being done is much more complicated than I posted above. So what actually happens is this query is inside of a For Each loop and finds one record each time goes through the loop and adds it to the drop down list. Since the query is done like this I cannot Order by the last name since it's only one record at a time being added to the drop down list.

Below is the Full code of what is going on:

```
 For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows 'Check each official for availibility and fill drop down list if needed



                    Dim col1 As Int32 = row.Field(Of Int32)(0)
                    Dim col1string As String = col1


                    'now get block info for each person
                    Dim SqlQuery2 As String = "Where ([Organization] = '" + Session("ID") + "' OR [Organization 2] = '" + Session("ID") + "' OR [Organization 3] = '" + Session("ID") + "') AND [ID] = '" + col1string + "'"
                    Dim NumOfBlocks As Integer = row.ItemArray.Count - 10
                    Dim strblocks As String = "Blocks"
                    Dim FirstChange As String = "No"
                    For i = 1 To NumOfBlocks
                        If i = NumOfBlocks Then 'Last one dont end with AND
                            Dim Num As String = i

                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field(Of String)(strblocks + Num)) Then 'dont include
                            Else 'include data
                                If FirstChange = "Yes" Then 'We have an AND

                                    SqlQuery2 = SqlQuery2 & "" + strblocks + Num + " <> '" + Session("DateTxt") + "'"

                                Else 'We dont have an AND

                                    SqlQuery2 = SqlQuery2 & " AND " + strblocks + Num + " <> '" + Session("DateTxt") + "'"

                                End If

                            End If
                        Else
                            Dim Num As String = i

                            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Field(Of String)(strblocks + Num)) Then 'dont include

                            Else 'include data
                                FirstChange = "Yes"
                                SqlQuery2 = SqlQuery2 & " AND " + strblocks + Num + " <> '" + Session("DateTxt") + "' And "
                            End If


                        End If

                    Next

                    'Trim String if it ends with just "and" so an error is not thrown in sql below
                    If SqlQuery2.EndsWith("And ") Then
                        SqlQuery2 = SqlQuery2.Substring(0, SqlQuery2.Length - 5)
                    Else

                    End If

                    con.Close()

                    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] + ' ' + [Email] + ' ' + [Phone] AS [FullInfo] FROM [Official]"


                    con.Close()
                    con.Open()
                    Dim dt = New DataTable
                    Using sqlconnecton = New SqlConnection(con.ConnectionString)
                        Using da = New SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery & SqlQuery2, con)

                            da.Fill(dt)
                        End Using
                    End Using

                    DropDownList1.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList1.DataBind()

                    DropDownList3.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList3.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList3.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList3.DataBind()

                    DropDownList4.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList4.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList4.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList4.DataBind()

                    DropDownList5.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList5.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList5.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList5.DataBind()

                    DropDownList6.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList6.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList6.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList6.DataBind()

                    DropDownList7.DataSource = dt
                    DropDownList7.DataTextField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList7.DataValueField = "FullInfo"
                    DropDownList7.DataBind()
                    con.Close()
                Next
```

Comment: Why you don't sort directly in your SQL query?

Comment: I made an update to my post as to why I cannot do this is the sql query. I over simplified my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue by creating an array list and sorting that. This was found at: http://codeintheoven.blogspot.com/2012/01/what-are-we-cooking-today-one-way-of.html

This examples code looks like this:

```
Private Sub SortDropDown(ByVal ddl As DropDownList)


    '---Get listItems from dropDownList
    Dim ddlList As New ArrayList
    For Each li As ListItem In ddl.Items
        ddlList.Add(li)
    Next

    '---Sort arraylist
    ddlList.Sort(New ListItemComparer)


    '---Copy sorted list back into the dropDownList
    ddl.Items.Clear()
    For Each li As ListItem In ddlList
        ddl.Items.Add(li)
    Next

End Sub
```

AND This:

```
Public Class ListItemComparer : Implements IComparer


Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Object, _
      ByVal y As Object) As Integer _
      Implements IComparer.Compare
    Dim a As ListItem = x
    Dim b As ListItem = y
    Dim c As New CaseInsensitiveComparer
    Return c.Compare(a.Text, b.Text)
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT [First Name] + ' ' + [Last Name] + ' ' + [Email] + ' ' + [Phone] AS [FullInfo] FROM [Official] ORDER BY [Last Name]"
```

Comment: This works for my original question that was oversimplified. I should not have tried to simplify my code for my question and have made an update in OP.

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.